# What exactly does prefetch in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, dataset

After loaded a dataset, I'm resizing and normalizing a training_set.

```
myTrain = training_set.shuffle(train_ex//4).map(resizeIMG).batch(32).prefetch(1)
```

Is there anyone could kindly help me to understand the proper use of prefetch?

Comment: What exactly is it that you don't understand? As the name and [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#prefetch) indicate, `prefetch` will grab the next dataset item "in advance" while the current one is being processed to reduce latency. Since dataset operations are usually done on the CPU, the idea is that you can take advantage of the unused CPU power (and I/O bandwidth) while the GPU is processing a batch (although I suppose it would work the same with multiple CPU cores).

Comment: Thanks. specifically, it is not clear to me when I need to use it and which is the best amount of items to prefetch. From the doc they say: 'This often improves latency and throughput, at the cost of using additional memory to store prefetched elements'. So 'often', can I use it in every kind of model? Is there a model that performs better without using prefetch? Which is the best amount of items I should prefetch?

Comment: I'm afraid that depends on the case, the general advice is to use it, unless maybe each batch takes a huge amount of memory and you don't want to use more than the strictly necessary or something. It's easy to measure if it has any impact though checking the average time per batch. The common thing is to prefetch just one, as long as you consume one dataset item (one batch) per training step. Again, you could test if prefetching more makes any difference to the timings, but is unlikely. You don't want to prefetch a thousand items "just in case" though, as each prefetched item takes memory.

Comment: Just to keep an example, I tried to prefetch(1), prefetch(128) and also not using it. At the end I didn't notice any change. I guess could make the difference using a very very large dataset. Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: Well there are two factors that influence whether or not it makes a difference. On the one hand, the longer it takes to read a batch, the more difference it will make. If your examples are e.g. 50-element vectors, it is less likely to have an impact than if they are high-res JPG images (using `.cache()` also affects this). Otoh, if the model is not too big, then maybe it will run very, very fast, so for example if running the model takes 10% the time it takes to read a batch, then the overlapping of computation and I/O doesn't give you that much.

Answer (score 2):

> Most dataset input pipelines should end with a call to prefetch. This
> allows later elements to be prepared while the current element is
> being processed. This often improves latency and throughput, at the
> cost of using additional memory to store prefetched elements.